# The given key does not identify an element in this collection value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {

vpc_id = aws_vpc.mod.id

cidr_block = var.cidr_subnet_private[count.index]

availability_zone = var.azs[count.index]

count = length(var.cidr_subnet_private)

tags = {

Name = "msi${var.environment}pvt${var.azs[count.index]}"

}

}
```

```
Error: Invalid index

│

│ on modules\tf-vpc\main.tf line 129, in resource "aws_subnet" "private":

│ 129: availability_zone = var.azs[count.index]

│ ├────────────────

│ │ count.index is 3

│ │ var.azs is list of string with 3 elements

│

│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the

│ given index is greater than or equal to the length of the collection.

╵

╷

│ Error: Invalid index

│

│ on modules\tf-vpc\main.tf line 132, in resource "aws_subnet" "private":

│ 132: Name = "msi${var.environment}pvt${var.azs[count.index]}"

│ ├────────────────

│ │ count.index is 3

│ │ var.azs is list of string with 3 elements

│

│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the

│ given index is greater than or equal to the length of the collection.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reformat your question. I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element` to circle over the `azs`:

```
availability_zone = element(var.azs, count.index)
```